# How to take a screenshot of a window which is not on top?

Tags: python, winapi, api-eveonline

I'm trying to develop a little tool for EVE online.

What I need to do is allow me to take a screenshot of its window by using WinAPI, even when it's not at the top of my screen.

I've tried this code, seems good, the only problem is it does not work on EVE online, it only returns a totally black picture. But it does work on other windows. Very strange.

```
import ctypes
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
from PIL import Image

def find_window_by_title(title):
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)
    if not hwnd:
        raise ValueError(f"window '{title}' not found.")
    return hwnd

def get_window_screenshot(hwnd):
    # get position
    left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)

    # get scale
    scale_factor = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(0) / 100

    # get size of window
    width = int((right - left) * scale_factor)
    height = int((bottom - top) * scale_factor)

    # get Device Context
    hwnd_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfc_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwnd_dc)
    save_dc = mfc_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()

    # create a bmp
    save_bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    save_bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfc_dc, width, height)

    # bmp > DC
    save_dc.SelectObject(save_bitmap)

    # save to save_dc
    result = win32gui.BitBlt(save_dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, width, height, hwnd_dc, 0, 0, win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # get bmp
    bmpinfo = save_bitmap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = save_bitmap.GetBitmapBits(True)

    # bmp > PIL
    image = Image.frombuffer(
        "RGB",
        (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
        bmpstr,
        "raw",
        "BGRX",
        0,
        1,
    )

    # release all resources
    win32gui.DeleteObject(save_bitmap.GetHandle())
    save_dc.DeleteDC()
    mfc_dc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwnd_dc)

    return image

def show_image(image):
    if image is not None:
        image.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window_title = "EVE Online Launcher"
    try:
        while True:
            hwnd = find_window_by_title(window_title)
            screenshot = get_window_screenshot(hwnd)
            show_image(screenshot)  # show it.
    except ValueError as e:
        print(str(e))
```

============2024.3.26 Update========
I found a C# implement of this, but I don't know how to deal with bitmap from CreateCompatibleBitmap() in python.

```
public IDwmThumbnail GetLiveThumbnail(IntPtr destination, IntPtr source)
    {
        IDwmThumbnail thumbnail = new DwmThumbnail(this);
        thumbnail.Register(destination, source);

        return thumbnail;
    }

    public Image GetStaticThumbnail(IntPtr source)
    {
        var sourceContext = User32NativeMethods.GetDC(source);

        User32NativeMethods.GetClientRect(source, out RECT windowRect);

        var width = windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left;
        var height = windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top;

        // Check if there is anything to make thumbnail of
        if ((width < WINDOW_SIZE_THRESHOLD) || (height < WINDOW_SIZE_THRESHOLD))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var destContext = Gdi32NativeMethods.CreateCompatibleDC(sourceContext);
        var bitmap = Gdi32NativeMethods.CreateCompatibleBitmap(sourceContext, width, height);

        var oldBitmap = Gdi32NativeMethods.SelectObject(destContext, bitmap);
        Gdi32NativeMethods.BitBlt(destContext, 0, 0, width, height, sourceContext, 0, 0, Gdi32NativeMethods.SRCCOPY);
        Gdi32NativeMethods.SelectObject(destContext, oldBitmap);
        Gdi32NativeMethods.DeleteDC(destContext);
        User32NativeMethods.ReleaseDC(source, sourceContext);

        Image image = Image.FromHbitmap(bitmap);
        Gdi32NativeMethods.DeleteObject(bitmap);

        return image;
    }
```

Comment: [New Ways to do Screen Capture](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/).

Comment: Developers of EVE online probably prevent you from doing this for example using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE. This will return black screens for every capture programm using official APIs (ie: w/o hacking).

Comment: `WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE` doesn't produce a black image, though (`WDA_MONITOR` would). But it's much more likely that EVE Online uses hardware acceleration (DirectX, OpenGL, etc.) without a GDI redirection surface, and `BitBlt()` is left in the dark, quite literally.

Comment: But a opensource project called EVE O-preview has the simular function, and approved by the developers of EVE online, so i don't think they will do anything to stop me from just get a screenshot. 
By the way, when my mouse is over the taskbar, it also can show the window thumbnail. So technically it should be able to do.

Comment: The link I posted shows you how to do that as long as you are on Windows 10 19H1 or later. Before that, there is no supported API to take a screenshot of an obscured window. The closest you can get is [`DwmRegisterThumbnail()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmregisterthumbnail) (which is presumably what the taskbar thumbnail preview uses internally).

Comment: That  C# implement is from EVE O-preview, definatily it should work, but when I try to use it to build a simple test, it always return the same picture, seems like something  stuck, and unable to refresh.